# Multiple For Loops in Batch Script on same Content

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, sendto

I set up a batch (copy.bat) file in my Windows sendto Directory that is for Copying a bunch of files via rightclicking the directories and choosing sendto "copy.bat".

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set cnt=0
set cur=0

:files
for /R "%~1" %%F in (*.7z, *.avi) do (set /a cnt+=1)
shift
if "%~1" NEQ "" goto :files
echo !cnt! files found for copying.

echo Processing ...


set "DEST_DIR=E:\"
:while
for /R "%~1" %%F IN (*.7z, *.avi) do (
    if exist "%%F" (
        set FILE_DIR=%%~dpF
    set FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=!%%~dpF:%%~1%=!
        xcopy /E /I /Y "%%F" "%DEST_DIR%!FILE_INTERMEDIATE_DIR!"
    )
    set /a cur+=1
    echo !cur!/!cnt! done...
)
shift
if "%~1" NEQ "" goto :while

pause
```

If I run the first for loop alone it counts the files.
If I run the second loop on its own it copies exatly those files the other loop is supposed to count.
However, both loops in one batch file will somehowe conflict. The Filecount works correctly but the copy process delivers an error: "The Path of is too long". Between "of" and "is" there is an additional Space. The final `pause` will correctly wait for button press. I assume it has to do something with the `%%F` variable, but renaming it in one of the loops does not help.

Comment: First advice: Do not put any files other than shortcuts into SendTo. Creat a shortcut, `.lnk` file with your target as the actual batch file located in an appropriate and easily managed directory within your usual filing area.

Comment: Thx for that advice. This way its easier to edit the files.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the name of your `.bat` - `copy` is a keyword to `cmd`.

Your problem is that the first routine `shift`s out all of the parameters, so your second routine has no parameters to deal with.

The easiest way is probably:

```
set "DEST_DIR=E:\"
call :while %*
pause
goto :eof

:while
for /R "%~1" %%F IN (*.7z, *.avi) do (
...
if "%~1" NEQ "" goto while
goto :eof
```

which executes the second routine as en internal subroutine (the `:` in the `call` is required) providing that routine with a fresh copy of the parameter-list (`%*`)

You could also consider moving the `if "~1"...` to the start of the routine (just after the `:while`), change it to `if "%~1" EQU "" goto :eof` and change the final statement to `goto while`.

The label `:eof` is defined as end-of-file by  `cmd` and should not be declared.